# UML composition attributes not feature in the class?

Tags: oop, uml

I have a class A and it has data members of class B and class C which are composition relationships. As I am going to draw a composition relationship line from B to A and C to A, does this mean I cannot also include the data members within the class A "box" because the relationship is inferred from the composition relationship lines?

I ask because the data member variable names seem a good way to help understand the context and this cannot be represented if you omit the data members from the class A "box"??

I am not sure if there is a cast-iron rule in UML or whether I am free to choose. This is not for auto-generation of code- just human reading.

Answer (score 1):

At least, in UML you can show a name of each property like a figure below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to UML specification, both representations of data members, **visually depicted association/composition** between two classes or **in-class data member display**) are equivalent. Here is an example (a little bit modified your case, to make it clearer):

[image]

Note that association end also show the scope and collection type (besides the name of course). col_B is defined ase private {ordered} collection (like array).

So, getting back to the formal side of UML spec... a, x, aa, col_b and m_c are all co called A's **structural features** (or **properties**). They can all be visually depicted using relationsips between the classes or inside the class itself. You can even show "int" data type as a class and link it using a composition!

Which way you will use is up to you, kind of matter of personal taste.

I always apply a simple rule - basic data types (int, boolean, date, string, etc) and their arrays are showed in the class itself, while the class and enumeration based properties are depicted by a relationship (example on the top).

As simple data types are clear and well known and does not have their own properties, I find it clear enough to show them in-class (diagram is simpler and smaller).

The complex data types (classes and enumerations) however typically have their own properties (data members, associations), even inheritances, and I want to make the class structure stand out on my diagarm.

You can use your own logic though.

Answer (score 0):

In a class diagram you cannot model the same composition both showing the association and the attribute, because in the UML semantic that would mean your class has *two* composition :-)

If in your diagram you already have classes B and C, I suggest you opt for the association ("relationship lines") solution.

To better understand the context, you can put the roles on the association: this is equivalent to the name of your attributes.